# How to Parse and store previous day from JSON API

Tags: json, swift, codable

The code below access the most recent data from the API and stores it in the corresponding struct.

I now need to access the 4 previous days and store them but i don't know where to start in accessing the data structure or if its even possible to do that without saving the information to a database for access later.

```
    struct Root: Codable {
    let metaData: [String: String]
    let timeSeriesFX5Min: [String:Forex]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeSeriesFX5Min = "Time Series FX (DAILY)"
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
    }
}


// MARK: - TimeSeriesFX5Min
struct Forex: Codable {
    let open, high, low, close: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case open = "1. open"
        case high = "2. high"
        case low = "3. low"
        case close = "4. close"


    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let jsonUrlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"

        let urlObj = URL(string: jsonUrlString)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                print(forex.metaData)
                if let latestTime = forex.metaData["4. Last Refreshed"], let latestForex = forex.timeSeriesFX5Min[latestTime] {


                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            }.resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: The `FX_INTRADAY` parameter sends only data from today.

Comment: My mistake i pasted the wrong api key, the problem still remains though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key of `timeSeriesFX5Min` (better `timeSeriesDaily`) is `"Time Series (Daily)"`.

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let metaData: [String: String]
    let timeSeriesDaily: [String:Forex]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
    }
}
```

The easiest way to filter the latest 4 entries is to get the keys, sort them descending and extract the first 4 values for the given keys from the dictionary

```
let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)

    let sortedKeys = forex.timeSeriesDaily.keys.sorted(by: >)
    let requestedKeys = sortedKeys.prefix(4)
    var requestedPrices = [String:Forex]()
    requestedKeys.forEach{ requestedPrices[$0] = forex.timeSeriesDaily[$0] }
    print(requestedPrices)
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but i have a quick question, how would you store each day separately so that you could use them individually? Would you have to store each day into their own struct?

Comment: The result (`requestedPrices`) is a dictionary. The keys are the dates and the values are the corresponding `Forex` structs.